# Spring Integration: How to read the unconsumed messages in the queue?

Tags: java, spring, queue, spring-integration, message-queue

I'm trying to read the unconsumed messages in a queue-channel. But couldn't find a way to do it. Is it possible? And if yes, kindly point to the right documents.

The purpose is to expose an API, such that the client can see the pending items on the UI.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You can simply reference the "queue-channel" in one of your ServiceActivator and do whatever you want with the messages:

```
@MessageEndpoint(value = "jobQueuer")
public class JobStartupQueuer {

    @Resource
    private Queue<Message> jobChannelQueue;

    public boolean accept(Message<?> message) {
        LOG.info("Channel size: {}", jobChannelQueue.size());
        return true;
    }
}
```

So the jobChannelQueue gets injected so in your ServiceActivator processing method (e.g. accept) we can reference the queue and its inner messages.